# SDM package R, predict function

Tags: r, gdal, glm, rgdal

I am currently trying to make an SDM with the sdm package. Everything works fine until the predict() function which should allow me to extend my model and get a prediction map. Indeed, the function returns me the following error message:
*Error in .updateGDAL(object, v, cell, band, setminmax) : no longer supported*

Here is my code:

```
lst <- list.files(path="C:/ACCESSVARIABLES", pattern='asc$', full.names=T)
lst

# COMBINE MY VARIABLES#
preds<- stack(lst)
preds


# SDMDATA #
d<-sdmData(formula=OCCURRENCE~ poly(bpi03,2) + poly(depth,2) + poly(vrm03,3) + slope, train=species, predictors= preds)
d


# SDM - GLM #
m1<- sdm(OCCURRENCE~ poly(bpi03,2) + poly(depth,2) + poly(vrm03,3) + slope, data=d, methods=c('glm'),  family= binomial,
         replication=c('cv', 'boot'), test.p=30 , n=5)
m1


# ROC + AUC #
roc(m1, smooth=T)



# PREDICT #
p1<- predict(m1, preds, filename='p2.img', mean=T)
```

Could someone help me please ?